# Xcode6: IBDesignable and IBInspectable with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6

I have an Objective-C UI component that I'd like to make inspectable in Interface Builder with Xcode 6. Swift has the `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable` declaration attributes. Are they available also in Objective-C? How are they used?

Comment: We can't discuss it here, please ask at apple developer forums.

Comment: @Mario Why can't we discuss it here? You know [the NDA's been relaxed this year](http://nuzzel.com/sharedstory/06032014/oleb/apple_has_partly_lifted_the_nda_for_beta_releases), right?

Comment: Questions covered by a third party NDA have never been offtopic in StackOverflow. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/94488/162235

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The equivalents are IB_DESIGNABLE and IBInspectable—see [the documentation for Objective C examples](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014224-CH41-SW1).

Also, this year's WWDC video "What's New in Interface Builder" has its examples in Swift, but the presenter also mentions the Objective C equivalents in passing.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi Fixed. Apple moved the documentation from the pre-release section with the iOS 8 launch yesterday.

Comment: It is not working if you create a subclass of UIButton.. why?

Answer (score 85):

Code example:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface LOLView : UIView
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable UIColor *someColor; 
@end
```

Comment: @Satyam Can't you just set the view of the view controller to a view that has these macros in the header file?

Comment: How is it possible to make iBOutlet to be IBInspectable ? After I change it I no longer have the property circle that shows me that it's connected

Comment: Don't think you want to do that anyway? IBInspectable sets a property on an IBOutlet normally. Example:  Text colour (IBInspectable) of a UILabel (IBOutlet).

Comment: Will this work in the .m file or is it solely for use in the .h file of your custom view?

Comment: .h I suppose. Why would you want to do it in .m though?

Comment: I often declare properties in the .m so that they are not unnecessarily exposed to the outside world

Comment: Ah the IBInspectable, yeah