# How can I use macro to set Font size in a nib file or storyboard without coding?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xib, nib

The problem is:

I want to define some macro to set labels font in global, so that it will be easier to change all labels font later:

```
#define kYXFont_F1 18
#define kYXFont_F2 16
#define kYXFont_F3 15
#define kYXFont_F4 14
```

or

```
#define kYXFont_F1 [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]
#define kYXFont_F2 [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]
#define kYXFont_F3 [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]
#define kYXFont_F4 [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]
```

I know that I can make it work in .m files. But the App has so many labels that the work amount may be too large. Is there any ideas to make the macros work in xib?

If there's no way to do that way, any good ideas to solve the problem with less codes?

Edit:

What I want to reduce is dragging lots of labels and write codes for those labels one by one, not the macro's definition style. Font_F0~F8 is declared by our UE Team.

Comment: Read this post on SO. this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465679/xcode6-ibdesignable-and-ibinspectable-with-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

```
#define kYXFont(size) [UIFont systemFontOfSize:size];
```

and then

```
someLabel.font = kYXFont(18);
someLabel1.font = kYXFont(16);
someLabel2.font = kYXFont(14);
```

Comment: What I want to reduce is dragging lots of labels and write codes for those labels one by one, not the macro's definition style. Font_F0~F8 is declared by our UE Team. Thanks anyway.